# Smoke hi-res fire artifacts in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation, volumetrics, artifacts

When rendering smoke/fire simulations with cycles I sometimes get some random lines/artifacts on my render. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

There are also some issues with transparency, but luckily they are not too noticeable.

[image: Fire Artifacts]

Here are my rendering settings:

[image: Render Settings]

I'm using 2.77 rc2 and tried both CPU/CUDA. I've had similar artifacts with previous versions and CPU rendering.

***Edit:***

I've discovered that the issue is caused by Smoke High Res:

[image: no highres]

[image: highres]

Comment: Not using any compositing effects, are you?

Comment: Compositor is disabled here. Of course I found the culprit directly after posting :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is caused by Smoke High Res. It was fixed by applying the scale of the smoke domain (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>)