# Smoke banding in render

Tags: smoke-simulation

We're a small studio using Blender for VFX work.  I have a large simulation of a building on fire and noticed that the smoke is banding in the upper left corner as seen in the attached picture.  The bake alone took 3 days, so I would like to avoid re-baking if possible.  Does anyone know if there is a render setting that might fix this?
[image: banding]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/74740/how-can-i-remove-these-lines-from-my-smoke and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48670/smoke-hi-res-fire-artifacts-in-cycles

Comment: Possibly caused by the Volume Sampling step size which defaults to 0.1. Try reducing it for better volumetric granularity - although it will slow down rendering.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the *Cubic* volume interpolation method and *Distance* sampling. Settings supported on CPU only:

[image]

> **Distance sampling**: Best for dense volumes with lights far away.
>
> **Cubic**: Smoothed high quality interpolation, but slower.

Linear vs Cubic:

[image]

GPU support for Cubic interpolation is [added in 2.8 version](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Cycles#More_Features):

> Commit *2d92988f6bc4* & *f61c340bc15e*: CUDA and OpenCL rendering support for cubic interpolation with images and volumes.

Comment: I just tried switch to CPU and making sure those settings were enabled.  Unfortunately it's still doing the same thing. Would it have something to do with baking with the adaptive domain turned on?

Comment: @ChrisTempel no, adaptive is not the problem. Your simulation is low resolution and only the cubic interpolation will save you (it smoothes it). Try it in blank file on some low res dense smoke if it works.

Comment: @ChrisTempel it is weird that you don't see a render difference, can you upload 1 frame of the smoke for testing?

Comment: @ChrisTempel another thing to consider to achieve better quality in reasonable time is to buy a commercial simulation software that can simulate well multithreaded and with openCL acceleration. Depends how much 3 days are worth to you, but Houdini Indie is $270 (this can render up to 4k resolution).

Comment: Yeah, we're considering Houdini.  Aside from this, Blender also has been deleting all our bake files, even if the sim isn't done baking.  We have to back them up which sucks when they are averaging 1GB a frame.